# Turn off access_log for specific path while still allowing fallthrough to PHP

Tags: nginx

Here's my config:

```
server {
    root /app/public;
    charset utf-8;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location = /php-health {
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /nginx-health {
        access_log off;
        default_type text/plain;
        return 200 "Nginx OK";
    }

    location @app {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /app/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I put that `location = /php-health` block in there, Nginx no longer forward the request to my PHP app via `location @app`. I thought that with the absence of a `return` statement it would "fall through" to `@app` but it's just 404ing.

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably more or less hacky ways to do this, but changing the `access_log` setting is one of the things you can safely do with `if`.

For example:

```
location @app {
    if ($uri = /php-health) {
        access_log off;
    }
    #... the PHP directives ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a dirty hack, but can you try this one?

```
location = /php-health {
    access_log off;
    try_files /dev/null @app;
}
```